# How do I create trees 3-4-x trees with QuickGraph in C#?

Tags: c#, algorithm, tree

In C#, using QuickGraph library, is it possible to create 3-x trees and implement Tree Traversal PreOrder (Inorder, PostOrder) in search tree ?

I found no examples on how to do that in [QuickGraph documentation](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/documentation)